# How to use database (SQLite3) values in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, database, sqlite

When I want to check if a value from an HTML form equals to a value from the database (which it does) it returns false instead of true.

Do I need more code?

Code:

```
password = params[:password]
password_db = @db.execute('SELECT password FROM dtbs WHERE username=?', [params[:username]]) 
puts password #returns llol123 
puts password_db #returns llol123 

check = (password==password_db) 
puts check #returns false
```

Comment: It might be that you have a whitespace symbol in the database before or after your password string. i.e. instead of [llol123] you have [ llol123] or [llol123 ]. That might cause this issue.
try puts "[#{password_db}]" and puts "[#{password}]" to see if you have any unwanted whitespace.

Comment: I'd recommend using an ORM rather than writing your queries by hand. [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) is my recommendation. A good ORM allows you to concentrate on the code and let it handle the generation of the queries. If you want to change to a different DBM you only change the connection information and the ORM handles the rest for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the return type of the password_db is in an array or something? Try getting the type of the values

```
puts password.class
puts password_db.class
```

I'm guessing they are different.

Comment: how do i do an inspect?

Comment: `password.inspect`

Comment: also if they are both arrays then this should work `password.eql?(password_db)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `(password_db[0]==password)` returns true.

That's the best way.

Comment: Based on what you're saying password_db is an array and password is a string. They are different types :)

Comment: or you have multiple values in password_db